# I need to use variable with TABLE type in IN operator

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need help with PL/SQL. How can i use variable with TABLE data type (in my case this variable involve 3 VARCHAR2 elements) with IN operator, without use access by index?
Example

```
select field1
from dual
where field1 in (myTableVariable);
```

myTableVariable must returning from function.

Not finished function:

```
declare
    v_string varchar2(100);
    v_string2 varchar2(100);
    TYPE V_ARRAY IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10)
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    result V_ARRAY;
    n number;
begin
    n := 1;
    v_string := '13,15,02';
    while v_string != ' ' loop
        select regexp_substr(v_string, '^[a-z0-9]*', 1), 
               regexp_replace(v_string, '^[a-z0-9]*(,|$)', '') 
        into v_string2, v_string
        from dual;
        result(n) := v_string2;
        n := n + 1;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_string2);
    end loop;
    return result;
end;
```

Comment: use where field1 in (select FieldToSelect from dbo.FunctionName(Parameters))

Comment: In function i want to return a variable with datatype TABLE, it is possible?

Comment: you can create table valued function in sql

Answer (score 2):

**First:**
Declare your table data type on the schema level (i.e. not in a package).

**Then:**

```
select field1
from dual
where feld1 in (select column_value from table(myTableVariable));
```

Enjoy!